Which route did Israeli jets use to bomb Iran on April 19, 2024?
Yesterday, Iran warned Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates that in the case of an Israeli attack using their airspaces, Iran cannot guarantee their oilfield's safety.
I am curious which route Israel used on April 19, 2024.
I.e., which one or more countries provided their airspaces to Israel?

Do note that sometimes things are not so much "provides its airspace" as "lacks the capacity to shoot down advanced military aircraft or the willingness to get involved in a war."

The question title and the question in the body are slightly different though. One is more about politics, the other less.

I have also meant to ask about the details of who (besides Western powers) participated in shooting down the Iranian strike on Israel in April.  These look like military-only questions, but they give a strong sense of how much Israel is/is not coming out of its regional diplomatic isolation (keeping in mind Arab governments foreign policy and their population's sentiment do not necessarily align).

Iran April 2024 strike.  : Jordan lies between Iran and Israel and had readied its air defenses to intercept drones and missiles that violated its airspace. Iran had warned Jordan against any possible action in support of Israel, but Jordan opened its airspace for U.S. and Israeli warplanes nonetheless. ... Haaretz reported that the Royal Jordanian Air Force had downed 20% of the drones launched from Iran...

... Jordan stated that its military action was an act of self-defense in an effort to safeguard the nation's airspace, territory, and citizens. There was also criticism towards Jordan's intervention that characterized it as having protected Israel.

TLDR:
To a large extent, it doesn't matter what happened, or what Iran believes what happened in April.  To be entirely cynical, one might say it doesn't matter what Iran believes might happen now:  it's a way to put Saudi on notice that they are at risk if they facilitate Israeli strikes in any way.  Airspace sovereignty is an easily understood concept and this is a shorthand for:  "Be careful, buddy, you're at risk * if you get involved!".

First, there is some dispute what the nature of the attack was, with some talking about drones, some talking about aircraft.

ISW - aircraft
Al Jazeera - drones
ISIS (unfortunate name, but different) - first thought to be drones, then aircraft.

(The two are not incompatible, with IAF possibly timing aircraft to coincide with drones.  One deadly drone attack on a US base in the Middle East was timed to match the return of a US drone)
Regardless, if the IDF used planes to shoot at Isphahan, their flight route would most probably be over Syria and Iraq, to avoid dealing with a fallout with more Western aligned countries.  I also doubt Iranian airspace would itself be extremely dangerous to an air force as sophisticated as the IDF.  To a large extent, the same reasoning about the sophistication of Saudi's air defenses vs Syria/Iraq, as well as the political risks, would apply regardless of whether planes or drones were used.
So, that's the sense I am answering in:  comparing likely flight paths in April to Iranian pressure about airspace in October.

Some additional corroboration from  Israel's October 26 2024 which got a lot more coverage
ISW's analysis:

The IDF struck several locations in Iraq and Syria immediately before launching strikes into Iran.9 The IDF was likely targeting early warning radars and sensors that would have given Iran advanced notice of the incoming Israeli attack. Iran has in recent years worked to build an early detection network across Iraq, Syria, and Lebanon in order to better defend against Israeli airstrikes.


That the IDF hit these batteries highlights the relative vulnerabilities of the S-300, especially against advanced platforms like the F-35 fighter jet.

(So, yes, that strike, Oct 26th, was using aircraft and went through Syria, even if it might have used F35s which I thought wouldn't reach.  Of course, those aircraft then launched missiles from as far away as optimal).
Times of Israel

Warplanes operate freely over skies of Islamic Republic in unprecedented op, with Israel saying it hit air defenses, key missile and drone sites, in response to ‘months of attacks’.

(ok, that is a bit rah-rah, but it makes it clear what systems were used and the relative lack of worry the IAF has about Iran's air defense systems).

The first wave of attacks apparently targeted Iran’s air defense capabilities, both to ensure the IDF’s freedom of operations during Saturday’s sorties and to lay the ground for further strikes should Iran retaliate.


As the campaign was underway, Syrian state media reported that Israel struck several military sites in the south and center of the country, possibly to enable the IAF to operate more freely in Iran.


It (the IDF) said dozens of IAF aircraft, including fighter jets, refuelers and spy planes, participated in the “complex” operation some 1,600 kilometers from Israel.

No, we don't know that October 26 == April 19, but the latter certainly follows IDF procedures we've seen over decades.  The thing I found really surprising is that they would risk air refueling over some of those hostile countries, even if that would then allow the use of shorter ranged assets like F35s (which are ideal for this job).  That's a calculated risk, but it also indicates a certain disdain for their air defense capabilities.

From a quick perusal of maps, a strike @ Isfahan in Iran on an S-300 battery, I would venture that Syria and Iraq kindly volunteered their airspace.  Probably F15 Strike Eagles given the range (they hit PLO @ Tunis once, though that would be easier with over-Mediterranean refuelling).
Ah, yes, confirmation of my idle speculation:

In the attack’s aftermath, however, Iraqis found what appeared to be remnants of surface-to-air missiles south of Baghdad. That, coupled with a suspected Israeli strike on a radar station in Syria the same day, suggests Israeli fighter jets flew over Syria into Iraq, then fired so-called “standoff missiles” into Iran for the Isfahan attack.

That's not a huge problem with Syria, which as at near war with Israel anyway.  Iraq isn't particularly friendly with Israel either, and can be chummy with Iran.
So, yes, of course, the subtext is that Iran will retaliate against any "neutrals", or not-anti-Israel-enoughs that facilitate strikes on it.
But neither country may have the capability to block jets - Syria frequently gets bombed by the IDF - and in any case, a strike force may stay off radar.
A strike on the Iranian oil export terminals though, as they are further away, may mean two things:
a) flying over Saudi
and/or
b) refuelling.  Now, a flying strike fighter over Iraq/Syria is one thing.  Trusting a refueling aircraft...  and there is no say Saudi could claim not to have seen that.
Reuter re. Kharg Island 

Most of its oil and gas wealth is located in the south of the country, where the Kharg Island terminal is situated and from which around 90% of Iranian oil exports are shipped.

Saudi just got out of the Yemen/Houthi war so it's not an entirely idle threat to them.
Hmmm... not sure about that refuelling needed bit (something the Economist claims).  Isfahan wasn't much closer than Kharg.  And the IAF is pretty good at long distance strikes.  At a guess, the Kharg route and the like means more overflight of Iraq, rather than Iran.

Kharg, 1510 from Haifa
Isfahan, 1558 from Haifa

DW has a nice write up here.

* Abqaiq–Khurais attack (by Houthis) Sept 14, 2019

Saudi Arabian officials stated that the attacks forced the shutdown of the facilities, cutting the country's oil production from 9.8 to about 4.1 million barrels of oil a day, losing 5.7 million barrels of oil a day or about 5% of global production.


I do not know anything about these things, but this makes no sense to me.  How does "remnants of surface-to-air missiles south of Baghdad", which by definition are launched from the surface against aircraft and mostly have ranges less than the distance from Iran to Baghdad, "suggest Israeli fighter jets flew over Syria into Iraq"?

well, looking at the map, an IAF jet would head ENE over Syria then bank full East over Iraq in order to approach Iran.  The Iraqis could just choose to shoot at an overflying military jet while it is transiting over Iraqi airspace. @User65535  Baghdad is in the north of Iraq so that fits... loosely.

So the implication is they were Iraqi SAMs?  I assumed they would have a more functional air defence system than that, and the implication was that Israel had their permission.

@User65535 They could also have been Iranian SAMs located near the border. I wouldn't read too much into their stated ranges: those are often underestimates by the manufacturer, and anyway they measure the effective engagement range (keeping some of the missile's fuel in reserve to counter maneuvers by the target) and not the absolute maximum range that the missile can fly if it doesn't hit anything.

@User65535 SAMs are not foolproof against sophisticated and savvy opponents, between radar dodging, electronic warfare and at times anti-SAM strikes.  Iraq used to have lots of Soviet ones (that didn't amount to much) but after the 2003 war, I don't know if they're replaced them that much.  Fighting ISIS is not a SAM thing.  That brings up the next issue, what do you do, now, if you've shot and missed someone violating your airspace?  Do you complain loudly, and admit you "failed" to protect yourself?  Or do you mostly keep mum to avoid the embarrassment?

TBH, I don't find that story particularly credible. No antiradiation missile has the range to fly from the Iraqi border to Isfahan. Given the target hit (an S300 radar), they most likely flew a single Harop to it. About 400km (disclosed) range. That would mean it was launched either covertly from inside Iraq, the Gulf, or even the Caspian Sea. Azerbaijan is a bit too far. Quite possibly though, Israel might have a "Harop ER" with longer range. There were also some 2018-2019 stories that the IAF successfully infiltrated the Iranian air space with F-35s and flew over cities, but again YMMV.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57387/were-there-remnants-of-surface-to-air-missiles-found-south-of-baghdad-after

Answers should be based on properly-referenced facts, not on speculation. Most of this is irrelevant to the question.

@StuartF Errr...  you must have missed the link I gave citing a press article with exactly that.  Have a nice day.

Despite your quickness to accept an answer, and even assume they flew jets it's not a given that's what happened in April.
If they did fly jets and they were detected far enough for a SAM to land the Iran-Iraq border (as the accepted answer says), which is hundreds of km from Isfahan, Iran would have probably scrambled more of their air force, closed down their airspace to civilian traffic, or even--you know--not do that and possibly shoot down another civilian airliner. BTW, I found 3 different versions of what was actually found in Iraq that day: "surface to air" missile, "Bombay type air to surface" (WTH "Bombay" means there, IDK), and finally "components of two Israeli missiles". So YMMV on all of these.) Also the place where all this mysterious stuff was found ("Latifiya") is 100km from the border with Iran. Anyhow, one of those three piece claims

Military observers speculate these fragments likely belong to the “Blue Sparrow” Air-Launched Ballistic Missile (ALBM), developed by the Israeli defense company, Rafael.

Which would also make some sense as a method of attack, but the missile might have been fired from way off for the booster to land there. (That's what's shown in the pictures--a booster.) Except the Sparrow as such is a non-warhead carrying target practice missile. (Of course, this could have been a modified version. Or some version/missile not know to the public thus far.)
FT also favors this but adds the thae missile in question has some 2000 km range! So it could have even been fired straight from Israel to reach Isfahan.



OTOH FT says/speculates that it was fired from Syrian airspace because of the concomitant Israeli operations there. And also that there's a ROCKS missile that uses the same booster as the Sparrow. Interestingly, Wikipedia adds that "The missile was first revealed at the 2019 Aero India show in Bangalore." And an Iraqi source talked about a "“Bombay air-to-surface” type" (instead of a surface to air). Which is the closest thing how "Bombay" might have come about in the Iraqi press reporting.

Amos Yadlin, a former Israeli air force general and military intelligence chief, said that regardless of how Israel conducted the strike on Iran, the mere fact that it took place would send a powerful message.
Commenting on the Iraqi images of the fallen missile segments, Yadlin added that they looked like parts of an “armament that has never been used before, with long-range capabilities”.


FWTW, Iran-aligned media claims that because the boosters fell where they fell, their warheads could not have reached 450km further into Iran, where Isfahan is, and that any damage there came from another source. IMHO, this [counter-]claim entirely depends on where the booster is intended to separate from the warhead. It's true that the boosters of many Iranian missiles that they fired at Israel in October also fell in Israel, so I'm guessing they are assuming Israeli missiles are designed the same way.
Risking a jet head on even with anti-radiation missiles against an S-300 is somewhat unfashionable since the Armenia-Azerbaijan wars, when the latter hit numerous Armenian SAMs with Israeli Harop drones, including an S-300. Harops have about 9 hour endurance, so perhaps around 1,800km range, one way. (Wikipedia gives much less than this, but it's probably disinfo--doesn't even match the manufacturer's endurance time claim. Size-wise they're comparable to Shahed 136--both at 2.5m long, and the latter do have that kind of range.) Enough to fly to Isfahan even from Azerbaijan, or perhaps even from Israel--that distance is some 1,500km. And Israel has been reportedly operating drones inside Iran from Azerbaijan for years. Anyhow, ISW notes that in the same day/night as the attack on Isfahan:

Iranian state media and local Iranian social media users separately reported air defense activity over Tabriz, East Azerbaijan Province, on April 18. Iranian officials told The New York Times that Israel attempted to conduct a separate attack on unspecified targets in Tabriz. IRGC-affiliated media claimed that Iranian air defense systems intercepted a “suspicious object,” which caused sounds of explosions over Tabriz. The IRGC-affiliated media outlet added that Iranian facilities in Tabriz “have not been exposed to any harm.”

Another possibility is a strike with a smaller drone, launched from insider Iran itself. Israel reportedly used these to strike some Iranian factories earlier on. (Personally, I think it's less clear who did those. Even Ukraine might have had the ability and the motivation.) Anyhow, not coincidentally, those were also in Isfahan. Iran claimed it successfully intercepted these, as Wikipedia says. Reality looked more like this. That kind of explosion is more than enough to disable a (phased-array) radar (like S-300 uses.
One analyst says that small drones might have been used in combination, to "stimulate" the radar to turn on and be targeted more precisely:

Drones could have been launched from even inside Iran and used to stimulate Iranian air defenses at the base, which would have given an anti-radiation seeker-equipped Rocks a perfect target to home in on, increasing its probability of kill drastically even if its GPS was severely disrupted. The presence of drones, or an EW/cyber attack that made them appear to be present, would also distract air defenders from the opposite end of the threat spectrum, an air launched ballistic missile.

TBH that only makes partial sense, as small drones are not targeted by S-300 in a typical (Russian) setup, but by accompanying Pantsir etc. And having those additional radars on would might have perhaps pulled the Rocks to less valuable target, although a lot depends how the radar seeker might have been programed (if one was even used).
N.B. there's one detail that makes the ballistic missile attack quite likely to have been successful without any radar seeker. The radar vehicle in question sat pretty at the peak of a mound that had been very likely erected so that the radar could "see" better (reduce ground clutter). So apparently the Iranians didn't move the radar around, like e.g. the Russians do near the front with Ukraine. (Russia even uses SAMs on top of towers these days, but much farther back from the front line.)
There's still some controversy how Haniyeh was killed in Iran, BTW. I've seen all sorts of stories from how he was blown up by a bomb placed in advance (Western officials' version), hit with a guided missile of some kind from an overlooking resort (Iranian version), or even been bombed (with a GBU-39 glide bomb) by an F-35, which allegedly refuelled over Jordan (if you can believe the two academic sleuths didn't mistake that alleged tanker for some other Boeing 707. TBH, they're probably wrong about the bomb at the very least. GBU 39 is too powerful to blow just one wall on one floor in that small building, even if that's been the effect in some larger buildings.)

FWTW, a few things that transpired since:

US leaks before the late Oct strikes talk about some more ROCKS missiles being prepared. And also a type until then (AFAIK) not discussed in public-- "Golden Horizon". Both ALBMs. (It's also unknown to the general public what the "RA-01" type of drone discussed in those refers to.)

Iran has claimed that Israeli jets fired from Iraq, without entering Iranian airspace. This is closer than what [some] Western media claimed previously, i.e. that they fired from Syria.


Unfortunately, establishing the true ranges of ALBMs is somewhat difficult.

Better footage from the 2022 war, where a Harop is heading straight for an S-300 (phased array) radar.

That's a lot of speculation.  Not least in that the range of the Harop is 1000 km max.  Don't confuse loitering with cruise speed:  loitering means bare minimum speed to orbit an area.  Several outlets on military matters claim planes and searching for "Harop" Isphahan strike gives 0 results.  While drones are certainly a new addition to modern weaponry, the IDF has been operating strike aircraft on this type of runs for decades so positing a sudden departure is speculative at best. -1

The warhead of a Harop would be good enough on a radar, at 23kg.  It would a joke on anything hardened.  Most of your writeup, and your links, don't have anything to do with anything Isphahan-specific and you just build it into a drone narrative.

@ItalianPhilosopher: and did they bomb anything else? Sure, cool stories about F-35s penetrating Iran's air space just to take photos have been going around for years. YMMV.

What's the combat range of an F35? 1300km in interceptor role.  Minus that issue, yes, they'd be a great pick.  With it, that's going to be borderline/problematic.  Again, lots of speculation.  And, again, Iran is not Ukraine or Russia with regards to having well-trained SAM crews.  One also wonders how well the US would react to the the prospect of an F35 crashing onto Iranian soil.

Interestingly, another ALBM, the "Air  Lora" was unveiled in June https://breakingdefense.com/2024/06/israels-iai-rolls-out-air-lora-a-new-air-launched-ballistic-missile/ No word on the range of the air-launched variant. TBH, the FT claim of a 2000km range for the ROCKS is somewhat questionable too. No other source, even the mfg (Rafael) brochure has any published range for ROCKS, except and Indian magazine that just says "well over 250 kilometres."

Published ranges of ALBMs are all over the place. For (the Russian) Kinzhal wikipedia gives "an estimated range of 460–480 km". But https://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/kinzhal-hypersonic-missile-russia/?cf-view gives "between 1,500km and 2,000km".

@ItalianPhilosopher: FWTW, as I'm somwhat skeptical of the FT range claim for the ROCKS  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/106974/can-the-kinzhal-really-fly-2-000km-or-can-the-rocks-at-least-its-warhead-is/

The question would not really belong here, if it wasn't for the political implications.  Political implications which don't really depend all that much on the weapon systems involved, unless no airspace anywhere was crossed (IRBMs, drones-launched-within-Iran).  But you've veered entirely away from those political considerations into back-and-forth, dubious, speculations about the capabilities of weapon systems that may or may not have been involved.  If this was a question, instead of an answer, it would be ripe for closure as not-about-politics-govt-etc...

And... drumroll... much of what you claim doesn't actually seem to have been the case on Oct 26th.  https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/iran-update-october-26-2024  : The IDF struck several locations in Iraq and Syria immediately before launching strikes into Iran.[9] The IDF was likely targeting early warning radars and sensors that would have given Iran advanced notice of the incoming Israeli attack.  and the consensus was that aircraft, inc. possilby F35s, were used (to launch missiles, obviously).
